# I would like to send my ERC20 tokens to my NFT minters

Tags: erc-20, nft

I'm developing the NFT marketplace for my ERC721 tokens.
I would like to generate the ERC20 tokens and distribute them to my NFT minters.
How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you need:

1. You create and deploy your erc20 token.
2. You go to the wallet that deployed it.
3. You send the token manually to the mint addresses.